# ROS v1.8.3 with android realm 4.1.0 sync issue

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

trying to connect ROS v1.8.3 with android realm 4.1.0, but got an error on connection:

```
Connection[1]: Writing failed: End of input 
Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error
Connection[1]: Reconnecting in 472 milliseconds
Connection[1]: Resolving 'ec2....us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9080'
Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint '34.215.139.88:9080' (1/1)
Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '34.215.139.88:9080' (from '10.0.2.15:35808')
Connection[1]: WebSocket::initiate_client_handshake()
Connection[1]: HTTP request =
                                                              GET /realm-sync/%2F0e38f9551d63d9e08f0d0bf%2Faccount HTTP/1.1
                                                              Authorization: Realm-Access-Token version=1 token="ey.......=="
                                                              Connection: Upgrade
                                                              Host: ec.....us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
                                                              Sec-WebSocket-Key: azTr3bmRnl1FbSvLCK0pvA==
                                                              Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: io.realm.sync.22
                                                              Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
                                                              Upgrade: websocket
```

is it version incompatibility issue?

previously it works well with realm 3.4.0 build. only changes i've made during migration:

project gradle:

```
 classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.0"
```

gradle:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    }
```

code (added `<SyncUser>`):

```
SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCred, serverH, new SyncUser.Callback <SyncUser> () {...
```

application have been deleted from phone before install with new realm build.

is some other options required?

logs on server:

```
sync: HTTP Connection[2165]: Connection is closed after HTTP response.
sync: HTTP Connection[2165]: 404 Not Found
sync: HTTP Connection[2165]: HTTP request received, url 
sync: HTTP Connection[2165]: Connection initiates HTTP receipt
proxy: attempting to upgrade client ::ffff:93.85.144.134:48862 => headers: {"authorization":"Realm-Access-Token version=1 token=\"eyJhY...Q==\"","connection":"Upgrade","host":"ec....us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com","sec-websocket-key":"Wtpq5fNSWwwJicg8E8/RTQ==","sec-websocket-protocol":"io.realm.sync.22","sec-websocket-version":"13","upgrade":"websocket"}.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm 4.0.0 was updated to use Realm Sync 2.0.x, which requires ROS 2.0 which is most likely incompatible with ROS 1.x.

The last version to use Realm Sync 1.x is `3.7.2`.